# External Tools configuration to execute command in Remote System

Tags: eclipse

Can one create an external Tool configuration (Run->external tools->config) to run a command batch in a connected Remote Systems (RSE) SSH Terminal/Shell? I tried but found no helpful documentation on that topic.

Comment: sure, just copy your script up to the server, grant execute permissions on it, and call it. for instance, I have a script called 'volcano.py' that I copied into /usr/sbin (which is on my $PATH). when I connect to the server over ssh, I just type 'volcano.py /local/path/to/server/dir' . what kind of shell does your server use? BASH?

Comment: @FrankThomas I don't want to type it all the time, but just press the "external tools" button in eclipse for that. Also i cannot copy a script to the server since it's a vm and I often switch to different snapshots. I basically needed to deploy the script to all snapshots which is not feasible.